# Python - Append letters in alphabetical order based on specific variable to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to append a letter (in an alphabetical order)to my dataframe starting from a specific letter which I have stored in a variable.

Current dataframe:

```
col1 
data1
data2
data3
```

Variable to assign (could be any letter of the alphabet)

```
variable ='D'
```

Desired output as dataframe

```
col1  | col2
data1 | E
data2 | F
data3 | G
```

I can assign ABCDE etc using the code below. For my case I have to assign it from a specific letter (e.g if letter `B` then next should be `C` etc

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ABC 
d = dict(zip(ABC[:len(df)], df.col1))
```

Desired output as dictionary

```
output = {'E': 'data1', 'F': 'data2', 'G': 'data3'}
```

Could someone guide me on the above?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord` to create start point for ascii code

```
start_ascii = ord(variable) + 1
```

Map using `chr` to the generated `ord` values

```
df['col2'] = list(map(chr, range(start_ascii, start_ascii + df.shape[0])))
```

Dataframe becomes

```
    col1 col2
0  data1    E
1  data2    F
2  data3    G
```

Convert to dictionary

```
dict(zip(df.col2, df.col1))
```

Output

```
{'E': 'data1', 'F': 'data2', 'G': 'data3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `RangeIndex`:

```
df["new"] = (df.index+ord(variable)+1).map(chr)

print (df.set_index("new")["col1"].to_dict())

{'E': 'data1', 'F': 'data2', 'G': 'data3'}
```

Comment: thanks - I keep getting: `ord() expected string of length 1, but NoneType found` my variable is: `var = A` - do I need to add quotation marks here or something?

Comment: Please ignore - it worked once I removed the `print` function in the code above

Comment: Note that this code might not work as expected if the dataframe index doesn't start with `0` or it isn't ordered.